# Looking for help on a script to iterate list of web server IP addresses and output screenshot of connected web page

Tags: windows, powershell, perl, full-text-search

thanks in advance for any help.  Is there a function in Powershell that will output the first rendered web page to a file from a list of IP addresses that are known web servers (IIS if that helps)?  Perhaps a function in Perl if there's no such animal in Powershell?  I would use the get-iisproperties function, but for most of the web servers I do not have rights (inherited VM guests w/o admin rights - fun fun).  Outputting what the web pages serve up for a large list will help identify the application owners and/or whether or not the pages are in use, etc.

Comment: When you say "first rendered" do you mean "as rendered by a specific browser"?

Comment: or when you say "first rendered" do you mean the homepage of the ip address?

Answer (score 3):

Read ip addresses from the file:

```
file $ip = Get-Content filename
```

This will get you array of ips.
$ip[0] == first line from file, $ip[1] second e.t.c.
Then create loop:

```
for ($index=0; $index -le $ip.length; $index++)
{
    $r = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://$ip[$index]/")
    $resp = $r.GetResponse()
    $reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
    $sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
    $result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
    $result >> fileoutput.html
}
```

Something like this. Sorry did not test. This should get you started.

Comment: Update to Powershell 3, get [`Invoke-WebRequest`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) which simplifies this considerably. Not to mention how nice it is to work with a HtmlWebResponseObject instead. :)

Comment: Yeah, i do not have a whole lot PowerShell experience as I am mostly nix python/bash guy. But you can definitely make it neatly done most definitely.